# When to use NSView's canDrawSubviewsIntoLayer (layer squashing)?

Tags: core-animation, calayer, nsview, appkit, nsscrollview

The benefits of setting `canDrawSubviewsIntoLayer = true` seem to mainly relate to a reduction in memory usage (reference: Apple 2013 WWDC talk 215).

I would think that this would be mainly beneficial for subviews that are more "static" in nature as opposed to subviews whose frames are effectively moving around a lot. I am trying to get clarity on this.

In particular: if you have a grid-like parent view (like `NSTableView` or `NSCollectionView`) where each of the child cells (custom `NSView` instances) is being moved around a lot (queued/dequeued/reused) to allow for scrolling, **would it be a good idea to have these cells drawn into the parent layer OR should they be treated as their own individual layers?**

[Just to be clear, the main consideration is scrolling performance.]